# Multiple selection in UITableView. And the tables are dynamically generated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, ipad

I have multiple uitableviews.
I created the multiple tables by using a loop.
The number of tables depend on the result of the webservice.
And each table have multiple selections. I have to pass all the values selected from every table to next webservice.

How can I do this task ?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

1-> you can use check Boxes for in your `UITableView` for mutli section (Check box can be implemented by `UIButton`). one check box per row.

2-> Use a flag (`BOOL isSelected`),set it true when user select a cell `(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`,and make it false for next touch,

for second approach you could use a custom `UITableViewCell` and use a image to show cell selection to the user (image can be changed by using `isSelected` value in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.